# ffmpeg lavfi distorted audio

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, rtmp

How to play audio at a normal rate?

First 2s play fine, then audio becomes distorted, it seems to speed up.

`ffmpeg -f image2 -loop 1 -framerate 25 -i example.jpg -lavfi "amovie=sample.aac:loop=0" -f flv rtmp://192.168.99.100:1935/live/mystream2`

Repeating audio with **loop:0** returns `[flv @ 0000000000708220] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0;

audio: http://cdn.online-convert.com/example-file/audio/example.aac

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amovie filter does not alter timestamps to make them continuous, upon loop. A setpts filter is needed.

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -loop 1 -framerate 25 -i example.jpg -f lavfi -i "amovie=sample.aac:loop=0,asetpts=N/SR/TB" -f flv rtmp://192.168.99.100:1935/live/mystream2
```

Comment: Audio loops now w/o an error, but it's stretching/cracking as **-framerate** gets changed, how to stabilize audio to a normal pace.

Comment: Show full console output and share a sample of the FLV

Comment: Output to static flv is fine, but outputting to rtmp gets speed distortion, seems video/audio are pushed at maximum cpu speed `frame=  142 fps= 32 q=7.7 Lsize=     872kB time=00:00:10.00 bitrate= 713.7kbits/s speed=2.24x`, seems audio plays twice as fast. The video/audio should be real-time at 25fps or so.

Comment: Adding -framerate 25 **-re** kept video at 1x rate, is there a way to lock it at exactly 1x?

Comment: Instead of `-re`, you can `-vf realtime` after the input name to accomplish the same thing. The `-re` strictly speaking only affects the input it is applied to.

Comment: Thank you, `-vf realtime` runs much better at exactly 1x or 0.999x most of the time.